# Publish to folder equivalent for a desktop GL project with visual studio Mac 2019

Tags: c#, monogame, visual-studio, publishing, macos

I'm not home so the only computer I have access to is a Macbook, and now I would like to see how I could pack up projects to export for various platforms. But when I build my project it only produce a windows executable. Since the project is DesktopGL I can execute it via the command

```
mono-sgen64 DesktopGL.exe
```

but this requires to include as redistributable the mono runtime. can't I publish the project in order to target Mac OS specific output and then get a fully packed .app executable like I can with the publish to folder thingy on windows?

I'll appreciate any help and really thank you for your attention.

Also if I could have access to linux executables I would be highly thankful.

Here is a recap of what I've found already:

> the publish to folder is only available for Mac with a .asp.net or core console project
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/publish-folder?view=vsmac-2019
>
> We can use appify.sh script but I don't know how it would read the content files etc. and this won't be compatible with linux
> I've allready used this script to create a packed php executable but I never included ressources
> https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/shell-script-mac-apps
>
> as I mentioned earlier I can execute the game properly using the mono executable so if I go that way I could create a run.sh script but this won't be the thing I'm looking into
> i figured it by looking where was located the actual executable of the game once I've run the project
>
> I've also found this nugget package which seems to add publishing parameters but I don't know if I can trust it
> https://www.nuget.org/packages/InfinitespaceStudios.MonoGame.Packaging/0.1.4-alpha

Comment: also I've remembered I could use wineskin but I really don't trust this thing

Comment: You don't need to include the runtime for a Windows build because Windows already has the .NET runtime built-in. Macs don't, so the user needs a Mono runtime or .NET Core to be able to run your managed code.

Comment: so in order to be able to execute the project I must include it?

Comment: when I create a monogame.macosx project, the game is built correctly as a .app package, I think I'll do an other project based on that and copy the code to export to Mac. (I'll use a git with only the code)

Comment: Sounds like you've answered your question. Be sure to post the steps of your solution as an Answer below.

Comment: yes I'll do it once I'll be able to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to create a .app executable for Mac OS with a DesktopGL project from Visual Studio Mac 2019 , you can create a second project and make a git that shares the code for the two projects. Then you can just compile the MacOS project and get your packed project but this is clearly a workaround rather than a real solution to the question I've asked. Else the easiest solution is to include the linux and the Mac OS executables for mono like said earlier.